# How to make structure in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using spring boot.In which I want if user_id is not available then save it else update data

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name="actorprofile")
  public class ActorProfile {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name="actor_back_profile_id")
  private int actor_back_profile_id;
  public int getActor_back_profile_id() {
    return actor_back_profile_id;
    }
  public void setActor_back_profile_id(int actor_back_profile_id) {
    this.actor_back_profile_id = actor_back_profile_id;
}
@Column(name="user_id")
public int user_id;
public int getUser_id() {
    return user_id;
}
public void setUser_id(int user_id) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
}
@Column(name="sub_profession")
private String subProfession;
@Column(name="other_profession")
private String otherProfession;
@Column(name="gender")
private String gender;
@Column(name="dob")
private String dob;
@Column(name="age")
private String age;
public String getSubProfession() {
    return subProfession;
}
public void setSubProfession(String subProfession) {
    this.subProfession = subProfession;
}
public String getOtherProfession() {
    return otherProfession;
}
public void setOtherProfession(String otherProfession) {
    this.otherProfession = otherProfession;
}
public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}
public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}
public String getDob() {
    return dob;
}
public void setDob(String dob) {
    this.dob = dob;
}
public String getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(String age) {
    this.age = age;
}
```

}
This is my DAO interface:

```
    public interface ActorDao {
    public ActorProfile updateProfile(ActorProfile profile);
     }
```

This is my DAOImpl:

```
     @Override
     public ActorProfile updateProfile(ActorProfile profile) {
     this.sessionFac.getCurrentSession()
     .createSQLQuery("UPDATE ActorProfile set 
      sub_profession=?,other_profession=?,gender=?,"
            + "dob=?,age=? WHERE user_id=?")
      .setParameter(0,profile.getSubProfession())
      .setParameter(1,profile.getOtherProfession())
      .setParameter(2,profile.getGender())
      .setParameter(3,profile.getDob())
      .setParameter(4,profile.getAge())
      .setParameter(21,profile.getUser_id()).executeUpdate();
       return profile;
```

This is Service:-

```
       public ActorProfile updateProfile(ActorProfile profile);
```

This is ServiceImpl:-

```
   @Transactional(readOnly=false)
   public ActorProfile updateProfile(ActorProfile profile) {
    return actorDao.updateProfile(profile);
      }
```

This is myController:-

```
     @RequestMapping(value = "/updateProfile/{user_id}", method = 
    RequestMethod.POST ,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
   public ResponseEntity<ActorProfile>  updateUser1(@RequestBody 
   ActorProfile actor,@PathVariable("user_id") int user_id) throws 
   IOException {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        String msg="";
        System.out.println("data is coming:"+actor.getAboutSelf());
        //Users user= new Users();

        if(actor!=null){

            actor.setUser_id(user_id);
            actorService.updateProfile(actor);
            msg="User registration Saved Successfully";
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<ActorProfile>(actor,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

now I have to write a method which will do two function at a same time that if user_id is present then it will update data and if user_id is not present then it will save data.
  Please anyone know how i will do that.

Comment: Use Spring JPA Repository to database related handling. its doing the same thing by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using spring boot, why not use spring data? It's easier and basically does what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: better be a comment!